# Alpha map in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to correctly show the eyelashes of a model. I am using alpha map for the eyelashes but I have no idea how to correctly set it up in Xcode.

See image below.

(the same alpha map is used in Blender and when set transparency all is good).

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Transparency mapping in iOS is different to anything I've ever seen in all my years of 3D/CAD.

You must use a .png file with transparent areas transparent, and opaque areas as black.

Comment: We were doing it wrong apparently. Just like when the antennagate

Comment: Using a jpg with luminance of colors to derives transparency information **is**  supported. See [SCNTransparencyMode.rgbZero](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransparencymode/1462540-rgbzero)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell by just a screenshot of the settings but I guess that the problem is the UV Channel which probably should be `0` rather than 1 (unless your 3D model really has multiple channels).