# Alpha map is not working in scenekit swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have tray to apply diffuse, metalness, normal, roughness and Alpha map on model  but all map are working but only alpha map is not working. 
How to make transparent glass in scenekit? i have tray to below code in swift iOS. Can anyone tell me specific reason for this?.

```
if let finishMap = finish.finishMap {
      if let diffuseTexturePath = finishMap.diffuseMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: diffuseTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in
                material.diffuse.contents = imageObject
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

       if let metalTexturePath = finishMap.metalnessMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: metalTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in
                material.metalness.contents = imageObject
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

        if let roughnessTexturePath = finishMap.roughnessMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: roughnessTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in
               material.roughness.contents = imageObject
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

        if let normalTexturePath = finishMap.normalMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: normalTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in
                material.normal.contents = imageObject
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }
        if let transparentTexturePath = finishMap.transparentMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: transparentTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in

               material.transparent.contents = imageObject

                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355942/alpha-map-in-scenekit

Answer (score 1):

set your transparency map to rbgZero. there are a few transparency modes, the default is by alpha i think (not sure), if you want to use a grayscale image as a map then you need to use rgbZero

```
material.transparencyMode   = .rgbZero
```